# jQuery Syntax Help

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for some help explaining exactly what this line of code does in jQuery;

```
myString += $(settings.mySelector,this).css('display') === 'none' ? 'closed' : 'not-closed';
```

I'm unfamiliar with the syntax and some of the operators used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `settings.mySelector` value hypothetically contains a Jquery selector (see http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/, this part is fundamental in JQuery)
2. `$(settings.mySelector, this)` function (yes, `$` is a function) searches for the element specified in `settings.mySelector` selector, given the current selection context `this` (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery, this part is fundamental in JQuery)
3. `$(settings.mySelector,this).css('display')` gets the CSS 'display' property value of the selected element
4. `$[...].css('display') === 'none' ? 'closed' : 'not-closed';` is what is called ternary operation: if `css('display') === 'none'` is true, it returns `'closed'`, otherwise returns `'not-closed'`.
5. Finally, `myString` is concatenated (`+=`) with either `'closed'` (if the element described in `settings.mySelector` is not displayed) or `'not-closed'`

Comment: Thanks for all the great explanations here. It's been really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

It means this:

```
if ($(settings.mySelector,this).css('display') === 'none')
{
    myString = myString + 'closed';
}
else
{
    myString = myString + 'not-closed';
}
```

The strict equality operator (`===`) performs an equality check without allowing type-coercions.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(settings.mySelector,this).css('display')
```

This selects an element that is a child of `this` and matches the given selector, then extracts the value of the CSS `display` property.

```
x === 'none' ? 'closed' : 'not-closed'
```

This uses the conditional (`?:`) operator and evaluates to `closed` if `x === 'none'` or `not-closed` otherwise.

Finally, `myString += y` appends the value of `y` to `myString`.

Answer (score 0):

it's a tertiary if/then statement. it says, that myString+= (myString=myString+) the result of the first evaluation,  `$(settings.mySelector,this).css('display') === 'none'`

if that statement evaluates as true, meaning that they referenced element is hidden, then pass back 'closed' else pass back 'open'

so myString either `+='closed'` **or** `myString+='open'`